# Windows Desktop Context Menu

Tags: c#, windows, registry, contextmenu

Hi I am currently creating a C# windows program and I am trying to add a right-click menu to the desktop everything is being added to the registry correctly but when I right click the desktop it wont display all menu items on some, its like it has a limit on how many items are aloud is their a way to overcome this? BTW I am adding it all through RegistryKey.

here are some images of the problem...

[as you can see it shows three Items but their should be more...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca5pT.jpg)

[this one shows missing items in the third item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfAIU.jpg)

[this is a pic of the registry items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9AAN.jpg)

any help on this matter will be appreciated, also I have tried to use sharpshell but have failed to get that working, I have limited knowledge of C# but I am learning and have not worked with C++.